# Weak convergence of one Gaussian Process to another one- determined by covariance function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, covariance

I am wondering whether I can make this statement:
Assume we have centered Gaussian processes $G_n$ and $G$. Furthermore it holds that $Cov(G_n(x),G_n(y))\stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\rightarrow Cov(G(x),G(y))$.
As every Gaussian process is determined by its covariance function, is this convergence enough to claim the weak convergence of the processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Which sort of weak convergence? In the sense of pointwise convergence of the CDFs? Sure, that amounts to justifying a couple interchanges of limits. It should be a routine dominated convergence theorem application.

Comment: Yes, for example (there are many equivalent formulations of weak convergence). I am not sure whether it is enough to interchange some limits. The question is, whether the convergence of the covariance function is sufficient for the convergence or if we still need to show stochastic equicontinuity/tightness.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow missed the "process" part of your question.

Comment: Seems to be not so easy?

Comment: The following link may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433660/convergence-in-distribution-of-gaussian-processes